# Find exact word/string after some characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of values,
ex:
`['acvd MF50-107895 htrx867954', 'aasdsasdasdwg 12354 MF34-123445 hwertx86', 'sdfrgrwgvwewerf 4356 MF74-765980 hwer982fg']`

Tried regex to extract the values after character "MF".
Regex expression i am trying,

`x = re.search(r"MF", txt)`
the values after character "MF" i need to consider only next 9 characters, the sequence of characters other than spaces and the result should be like this `MF50-107895, MF34-123445, MF74-765980`.

Comment: I believe that, by *...the values after character "MF"* you mean *"MF" and the sequence of characters other than spaces that follow it*.

Comment: yes @CarySwoveland that's correct

Comment: You may wish to clarify that by editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
import re

[re.search("MF.*?\s", v).group().strip() for v in values]
```

---

```
['MF50-107895', 'MF34-123445', 'MF74-765980']
```

**Demo,**
https://regex101.com/r/VHFXji/1

Answer (score 0):

No need for a regex, use

```
>>> v = ['acvd MF50-107895 htrx867954', 'aasdsasdasdwg 12354 MF34-123445 hwertx86', 'sdfrgrwgvwewerf 4356 MF74-765980 hwer982fg']
>>> l = []
>>> for s in v:
    l.extend([x for x in s.split() if x.startswith("MF")])
    
>>> l
['MF50-107895', 'MF34-123445', 'MF74-765980']
```